# C# - Microsoft Graph API - Getting Pictures from Customlist

Tags: c#, api, sharepoint, graph

I tried to get a Picture from a Sharepoint customlist. I can read all columns form the list and I get the picture from an entry of a custom document lib with Graph API. But I can't access (or get to) the document lib where the pictures from the list are stored. The lib is under /..../SiteAssets/{ListId}. I can't go to SiteAssets. In the Browser I can do it.

```
protected async Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>> GetSpListItems(string siteId, string listId, IEnumerable<Option> spListItemQuery)   
 {
        var listRawContent = await GraphClient
            .Sites[siteId]
            .Lists[listId]
            .Items
            .Request(spListItemQuery)
            .GetAsync();

        var items = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var rawItem in listRawContent)
        {
            var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Id", rawItem.Id}
            };

            if (rawItem.Fields.AdditionalData is Dictionary<string, object> listrawItemAditional)
                foreach (var addContent in listrawItemAditional)
                {
                    data.Add(addContent.Key, addContent.Value);
                }

            items.Add(data);
        }

            return items;
```

}

That gives me the list items. One Item contains a Picture in one Field,
as follows :

{"fileName":"pic01.jpg","serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/NewsPanelz_Test/SiteAssets/Lists/5a86dd02-9583-48c5-bc6f-077f04181406/pic01.jpg","id":"2d1eac72-7167-46cc-a680-f8288f71bebe","serverUrl":"https://bxxxxx.sharepoint.com","thumbnailRenderer":{"spItemUrl":"https://bxxxxx.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.1/drives/b!UizO8Gx3p0-zhzRiSLs8VPdUqg0IsT5Dm5N7n-4YeTtpQAxoVMrLSZeU8bW8evTF/items/01TT42SR3SVQPC2Z3RZRDKNAHYFCHXDPV6","fileVersion":1,"sponsorToken":"L3NpdGV.....0cy9....zdGUxfEJpbGRkYXRlaXwx"}}

How can I get the picture ?

Michael,..,

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're fetching the value from an image column. This column does not store the image blob file in the list, it only references the storage location (site asset). You can access the image like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[site id]/lists/Site Assets/items/[you can get id from image column]/driveItem
```

[image]

Comment: If I fire [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/bbzslde.sharepoint.com,f0cxxxxxxxxxxx108-433e-9b93-7b9fee18793b/Site Assets/lists/] I got a bad request 'Resource not found for the segment 'Site Assets'

Answer (score 0):

You can extract from the "spItemUrl" the drive id and the drive item id.

With them, you can use graph api:

```cs
graphClient.Drives[DriveId].Items[DriveItemId].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

But sometime thumbnail Renderer is missing, and i don't know why...